# How to get the memory address of an object with `this` reference inside the class in C++

Tags: c++, reference, this

How can I get the memory address of an object inside a class with `this` reference in C++.

I can get the memory address of an object outside the class by using the following:

```
Obj obj();
cout << &obj << endl;
```

I want to do this with `this` reference. Something like:

```
void Obj::method()
{
    cout << &this << endl;
}
```

But the above code gives an error. Is it possible in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Obj::method()
{
    cout << &*this << " or " << this << endl;
}
```

Comment: Or just `this`.

Answer (score 1):

> I can get the memory address of an object outside the class by using
>   the following:
>
> ```
> Obj obj();
> cout << &obj << endl;
> ```

That is not memory address of an object of type `Obj`. That is the memory address of a function that returns `Obj`. A function pointer won't be printed by a stream though, and is converted to a bool instead, so you'll always see 1.

---

> ```
> void Obj::method()
> {
>     cout << &this << endl;
> }
> ```

You cannot take the address of `this`. You shouldn't either because what you want is the address of the object. `this` is already a pointer to this object, so simply don't use the addressof operator.